# Laravel 4 - remember me not working?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-4

I have implemented remember me functionality in my Laravel 4.2 project.

Here is how I login passing remember me checkbox value:

```
Auth::login($user, $remember);
```

In session.php I have 1 minute expiration for testing purposes:

```
'lifetime' => 1,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Now, when I login cookes are created, one for the session with expiration 1 min
and one for the remember_me with expiration 5 years.

After 1 minute the session cookie is expired and I am redirected to the login screen which is not what I would expect since remember_me was checked.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand in a minute session gone, maybe try to remember the user as it is written [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users), or bring the code exactly how you store session for more specific recommendations

P.S. Is there a remember_token field in the table users?

Comment: vydalylas :) zdorovenky buly.

Comment: Oh this Google translator. I'm So Sorry